# Why, conceptually, are identical bosons "pulled together" and identical fermions "pushed away"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, fermions, bosons, identical-particles

I have seen the calculation for the separation distance of indistinguishable particles versus distinguishable ones. According to Griffiths (Pg. 204 3rd Ed.), the difference in separation distance is $$\langle (\Delta x)^2\rangle_{\pm} = \langle (\Delta x)^2\rangle_{d} \mp 2 \vert \langle x\rangle_{ab} \vert ^2.$$ where a and b represent two particles a and b and d represents distinguishable.

My question is why, conceptually, are identical bosons "pulled together" and identical fermions are "pushed away"? Is there a reason to anticipate this a priori?

Comment: Fundamental reason: Spin-Statistics theorem (Wolfgang Pauli 1940).

Comment: These characteristics are true by definition.  As noted in the answer to [Intuition behind Pauli Principle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/445206/145491), bosons and fermions are actually defined by whether they are "pulled together" (i.e follow Bose-Einstein statistics) or are "pushed away" (i.e. follow Fermi-Dirac statistics).  Are you asking for an intuitive explanation why integer spin particles are bosons and half-integer spins are fermions?

Comment: @DavidBailey yes, i think so -- just how does spin lead to this pulling and pushing apart. i thought bosons and fermions were defined by their spin -- so confusing, it seems people contradict each other left and right! thanks for pointing me to this question. i will surely have a read. :)

Comment: Then your question is pretty much the same as these: ["Intuition behind Pauli’s Principle"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/445084/145491) or ["Why must fermions be antisymmetric?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/207459/145491). As @Hyperon says, it comes down to the [Spin-Statistics Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93statistics_theorem).

Comment: thank for helping me narrow down what the question is! I will read those pages for sure. @DavidBailey